# Difference between iOS Storyboard Segue Types

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, storyboard

What is the difference between a programmatic segue called by `performSegueWithIdentifier:` and a segue performed by dragging a UIButton to a view. I thought they would be the same but the former closes a UIWebView (facebook OAuth dialog) upon loading the view which is being "segued" to, while the latter does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to even call `performSegueWithIdentifier` you will still need to link up a segue in interface builder. The only difference is, calling the segue programmatically allows you to make conditions or custom triggers that will cause the view change. Not just clicking a button.